# Method declared in Class but not defined

Tags: c++, compilation, linker

I have Class which declares a method but does not implement it. The method is not a virtual function. In the corresponding cpp file I did not find the definition of the same method. All other methods declared in the class were defined.

I compiled the code and it went fine. I was of the impression that cpp must mandate the definition of a declared method.

Appreciate if somebody could elaborate on the same. I am using cl compiler from VS2010.

Answer (score 13):

Your code will compile but it will give linking errors.

Building an executable of your project involves two stages:

- Compilation
- Linking

During **Compilation** the compiler merely translates the source code into object code by verifying the language semantics.
During **Linking** the linker actually looks up for the definitions of the symbols and creates an executable from multiple object files (created during compilation).

The compiler compiles the source code in each translation unit (.cpp + header files) separately and hence it assumes the definition should be present in some other source file. It is the Linker who tries to find references to the function definitions, and hence the missing definition will be reported by the linker.

Note that the linker needs to link only those symbols which are *used* by your program,
For ex: If your program declares a function, provides no definition & then never *uses/calls* the function anywhere, the linker does not need to embed the code for jumping to the address where the object code for the function resides at any function call site.
Given such a scenario the linker will simply never need to look up for the function definition at all. Hence the code will compile and link.

Comment: IMHO, The linking error will happen only if the function with missing-definition is being used/called explicitly/implicitly somewhere.

Comment: I neither getting any compilation or linking error. Just to add I am not using the funtion anywhere. The code compiles and links fine into .lib file.

Comment: @akrohit as discussed above, if you are not using the function anywhere, you need not define it and there will be neither compilation error nor linking error.

Comment: @akrohit: I updated the answer for clarity perhaps I was not clear enough before and assumed some aspects.

Answer (score 3):

There's no requirement for the method to be implemented in a particular file. Indeed it is (or was) considered good programming practice to have one file per method to reduce bloat when linking with libraries.

This means that given a header file which defines a class (and presumably doesn't have the implementation in it), the compiler can only assume that all the functions are implemented somewhere. It's only at the point where the system attempts to put everything together (the link stage) that it becomes apparent that you are referring to something that isn't there.

Comment: not really. it makes for much less bloat and surprising link issues. Some modern compilers make that un-necessary by making each function live in a separate object section, but most don't.

Comment: I double checked and could not find the definition of the method I am talking about above in any other file also.

Comment: @RonaldMcBean - this is how it's done (mostly) in Linux and libc. If you look at the source code, you'll see individual implementation files for each POSIX/Linux kernel funcs (mostly for all of them.)

Answer (score 3):

It is a common technique to prevent assignment or copy. If you declare it but not define it, a linking error will occur if you try to use it i.e. prevents people using it inadvertently

Answer (score 0):

The compiler does not complain because there is no syntax/compiler error.
The linker does not complain because you are not calling the function in your program so it does not need to be linked.