# Static typing concept in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, static-typing, compile-time-type-checking

I am going through C++ primer (fifth edition). In that on page 46 'Key Concept: Static Typing' section it says and I quote

> As we’ve seen, the type of an object constrains the operations that the object can
> perform. In C++, the compiler checks whether the operations we write are supported
> by the types we use. If we try to do things that the type does not support, the compiler
> generates an error message and does not produce an executable file.

Do the authors mean that static typing (done by type checking) checks whether a type actually supports an operation, for example, if we have have defined a type 'Calc' with an Add() method, does the compiler actually verifies that Add() is defined as part of static typing?

Or do they mean that if the user of the type is calling Multiply() but if the doesn't have that then compiler checks it as part of static typing?

Which of these two are they referring to in this context?

I googled 'static typing C++ primer' and stackoverflow results didn't seem to have any related questions on this.

Comment: Your two statements seem to mean the same thing to me. A method must exist on a class to invoke it on an instance of that class

Comment: @AlanBirtles I think the first of the two options the OP is asking about is a situation when you declare a member function in a class, but never define it. In that case, the compiler will not complain, and, if you actually never use that method anywhere, then the linker will not complain either. Something like that was asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9209994/1458097

Comment: @AlanBirtles No Alan, they aren't the same. On second thought, it seems like it is the linker that checks if the method is actually 'defined' and compiler checks that you are not calling a 'non-existing' method of a type. So, for now I will stick with compiler does static typing using type checking to ensure that a method that you are calling from a type actually exists.

Comment: @heapunderrun -- it's not quite that simple. Typically, a virtual function must be defined even if it's not called.

Comment: @ZoomIn The compiler checks the first point, the linker checks the second.